# word2Vec and abbreviations

Tags: python, keras, nlp, word2vec

I am working on text classification task where my dataset contains a lot of abbreviations and proper nouns. For instance: **Milka choc. bar**.
My idea is to use bidirectional LSTM model with word2vec embedding.
And here is my problem how to code words, that not appears in the dictionary? 
I partially solved this problem by merging pre-trained vectors with randomly initialized. Here is my implementation:

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('ru.vec', binary=False, unicode_errors='ignore')

EMBEDDING_DIM=300
vocabulary_size=min(len(word_index)+1,num_words)
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocabulary_size, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i>=num_words:
        continue
    try:
        embedding_vector = word_vectors[word]
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
    except KeyError:
        embedding_matrix[i]=np.random.normal(0,np.sqrt(0.25),EMBEDDING_DIM)

def LSTMModel(X,words_nb, embed_dim, num_classes):
    _input = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
    X = embedding_layer = Embedding(words_nb,
                            embed_dim,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            trainable=True)(_input)
   X = The_rest_of__the_LSTM_model()(X)
```

Do you think, that allowing the model to adjust the embedding weights is a good idea? 
Could you please tell me, how can I encode words like **choc**? Obviously, this abbreviation stands for **chocolate**.

Answer (score 1):

It is often not a good idea to adjust word2vec embeddings if you do not have sufficiently large corpus in your training. To clarify that, take an example where your corpus has *television* but not *TV*. Even though they might have word2vec embeddings, after training only *television* will be adjust and not *TV*. So you disrupt the information from word2vec.

To solve this problem you have 3 options:

1. You let the LSTM in the upper layer figure out what the word might mean based on its context. For example, *I like choc.* the LSTM can figure out it is an object. This was demonstrated by [Memory Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3916).
2. Easy option, pre-process, canonicalise as much as you can before passing to the model. Spell checkers often capture these very well and are really fast.
3. You can use character encoding along side word2vec. This is employed in many of the question answering models such as [BiDAF](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3916) where the character representation is merged with word2vec so you have some information relating characters to words. In this case, *choc* might be similar to *chocolate*.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very good post.  I should have added a more detailed description of my problem. I am working on text classification where the size of the target vector is about 30k. Do you have any idea what model choose?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to add a function that maps your abbreviations to existing vectors that are most likely to be related ie: **initialize** the **choc** vector to the **chocolate** vector in w2v.

```
word_in_your_embedding_matrix[:len(abbreviated_word)]
```

There are two possible cases:

- There is only one candidate that starts with the same n letters as your abbreviation, then, you can initialize your abbreviation embedding with that vector.
- There are multiple items that start with the same n letters as your abbreviation, you can use the average as the yout initialization vector.